# How to refresh the header if another user has added something React Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

In my application I have a header in which I have information about the number of children in the kindergarten. How can I get data (number of children) when another user e.g. teacher adds a child to this kindergarten. Currently I have the interval function set at 10 seconds, is there any other way. I use node.js express

Comment: Either use the interval and poll every x seconds, or look at the Push API to have the server notify all of the clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want realtime update you can use websocket with socker.io library

With your client you subscribe to an 'onChildUpdate' and when a teacher add a children the node server send an event trought the websocket